# Android application size

Tags: android, filesize

When i export my apk is 600 KB in size. With installed on the android phone the Application size is 2.23MB why this happens?

This change in size occurs when i include asmack library but i can't figure out why such a size diff.

No files are generated in the package folder. Can anyone tell me why this happen?

Comment: I am assuming you are running proguard on your apk to remove unused classes, right?

Comment: no proguard used. Maybe be that asmack is obfuscated but how can i tell? Also how this had an impact on file size after install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a project is built, it is compressed into an APK file. This is similar to a zip file. When an app is installed, it is moved onto the file system of the device. At this time, parts of it are uncompressed and optimized to allow for faster and more efficient execution.